# Thread 1: Signal Sigabrt iOS App Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

In the main.m file of a project I am trying to create in XCode, I keep getting this error:
Thread 1:Signal Sigabrt.
The project was running fine until it began to crash on start due to this error.  Is anything wrong with this line, or does anyone have any suggestions concerning what else may have caused this?

return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C, Thread 1 Program Received Signal SIGABRT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294257/objective-c-thread-1-program-received-signal-sigabrt)

Comment: What is the error output in the bottom right?

Comment: Could you please provide the console output….

Answer (score 0):

Your main method should look something like this under ARC:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{    
    @autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Are you sure your AppDelegate class file (and associated xib files, if any) is indeed named "AppDelegate"?